# How to Perform a MultiTerms Aggregation using Script?

Tags: elasticsearch

In the elastic documentation it says I can perform multi-term aggregation if I use `script` ([reference](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html#_multi_field_terms_aggregation)). It is not clear to me how this is done. Basically what I am after is `count(*) ... group by logsource,pid`. Without a script, it seems I can only do one group by.

Can someone show me an example?

Answer (score 1):

Using script can be costly, but to answer your question,

```
POST /_search
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs": {
       "test": {
          "terms": {
             "script": "doc['logsource'].value+\":\"+doc['pid'].value",
             "size": 0
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Will do!

Answer (score 0):

I think by using sub aggregations I can get the intended result, take for example:

```
{
"query" : {
            "match": {
                "message": "error"
            }
},

"aggs": {
    "g_logsource": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "logsource"
        },
        "aggs": {
            "g_pid": {
                "terms": {
                    "field": "pid"
                },
                "aggs" : {
                    "ts" : {
                        "date_histogram" : {
                            "field" : "@timestamp",
                            "interval" : "1h"
                        }
                    }
                }   
            }                           
        }            
    }
}
```

}

Returns:

```
 "aggregations": {
  "g_logsource": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "nyhq",
           "doc_count": 2129,
           "g_pid": {
              "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 5,
              "buckets": [
                 {
                    "key": "5641",
                    "doc_count": 9,
                    "ts": {
                       "buckets": [
                          {
                             "key_as_string": "2014-12-07T04:00:00.000Z",
                             "key": 1417924800000,
                             "doc_count": 2
                          },
                          {
                             "key_as_string": "2014-12-07T08:00:00.000Z",
                             "key": 1417939200000,
                             "doc_count": 4
                          },
                          {
                             "key_as_string": "2014-12-07T18:00:00.000Z",
                             "key": 1417975200000,
                             "doc_count": 1
                          },
                          {
                             "key_as_string": "2014-12-07T20:00:00.000Z",
                             "key": 1417982400000,
                             "doc_count": 2
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 },
                 {
                    "key": "14839",
                    "doc_count": 3,
                    "ts": {
                       "buckets": [
                          {
                             "key_as_string": "2014-12-07T09:00:00.000Z",
                             "key": 1417942800000,
                             "doc_count": 1
                          },
                          {
                             "key_as_string": "2014-12-07T20:00:00.000Z",
                             "key": 1417982400000,
                             "doc_count": 2
                          }
                       ]
                    }
                 }
```

In my code, I can then combine groups to be `{logsource: nyhq, pid: 5641}` as the identifer for each time series. I think this is the same as `GROUP BY` in SQL. Would appreciate any comments confirming this.

Comment: @progrrammer What about this path, is this doing what I think it is?